# Date formatting using Moment library

Tags: momentjs

```
              data() {
            return {

              date: Moment().format("llll"),
              console.log(date)
        }
       }
```

The type of format that I am trying to achieve is: Mon, 2 Jul, however through what I have implemented so far I get: Mon, Jul 2, 2018 5:08 PM.
I am currently using the Moment date library https://momentjs.com/. however the one I am looking for is not listed in the documentation.

Comment: check this [Momentjs format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formatting is fairly self-explanatory [in the docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) on Moment's website. It's easy to work out the correct for your example. Here's what you need:

```
moment().format('ddd, D MMM');
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you are trying to format the date with "llll".

If it is for **locale settings** you can override the settings when instantiating locale (for example french) using an object:

```
moment.locale('fr', {
    longDateFormat : {
        LLLL : 'ddd, D MMM'
    }
}
```

And then return the date as

```
Moment().format("LLLL")
```

**If you are not using a specific locale** you can just go for what BenM wrote.